# Row level security in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi

I am not able to implement row level security to my report. I have tried different methods on google and Microsoft forums but all in vain. Could you please help?

I have a dataset name "Cases" which have details of all cases logged into system with its country.

Then I have dataset name "Escalations" with details of the all the escalations along with its country.

Then there is one more table called "Country Mapping" which contains all the countries mapped with their Regions and Region Manager.

I have already prepared a report showing Global /Regional numbers But now people want to restrict the data according to its own territory.

Example :- Some want to see global data and some are responsible for a particular country. I know RLS can help me with this. I have tried to make two tables one with Username and country responsible and other one with just usernames and names.

I have made a relationship between all these tables. But the problem with the code is, like if I am the admin of the report then I need to manually add myself in the country responsible for every country. Like 146 countries .

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: @ramdeep Can you please add an Image of your data model.

Comment: A shot of your data model and maybe a .pbix sample would be quite helpful.